# Working around the issue of being unable to acquire WiFi signal strength in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nehotspothelper

I have an iOS app that I had intended on adding a feature which shows WiFi bars to show the user their WiFi signal strength while the app is in full screen. As I have learned recently, it is not possible to include a feature in an iOS app which allows you to show the signal strength of the connected wireless network since Apple does not allow this unless you sign up to register for Apple's NEHotspotHelper and this is not a normal use case for this API.

To work around this issue, is there some way of still showing the user that their WiFi connection isn't good? Could I measure the latency of the connection is some way to show an alert saying the connection is bad? Are there any other symptoms of a poor wireless connection that I could measure to still implement this function in my app?

Comment: WiFi signal strength is only one indicator of network performance and not a terribly useful one at that.  What actually matters to your application?  Throughput?  Latency? Jitter?  A poor Wifi signal can adversely affect all of those, but even with a good wifi signal you can have unacceptable network performance depending on other factors such as the Internet connection, your server load, where the device is geographically in relation to your server.  You would do better understanding what network parameter(s) matter to your application,  then measuring and reporting on those.

Comment: More general comment can be - don't do this. Even if you find what network parameter(s) matter to your application, they can change in the blink of an eye. Imagine this - you'll say to the user that the network conditions are perfect, user will do some action and it will fail. Because, in the meanwhile, anywhere on the route, a huge problem appeared.